# Android http error

Tags: android, http

I am trying to download a file from my Dropbox but my app chrashes and the error logs speak about http errors, what did I do wrong? The error log just says "Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" then lists alot of http errors

```
private final String PATH = "/data/data/com.emiliogaines.fuelfinder/shared_prefs/";  //put the downloaded file here


    public void DownloadFromUrl(String fileName) {  //this is the downloader method
        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://www.dropbox.com/s/1793397jyxorw6g/testDoc.xml?dl=0");
            File file = new File(PATH + fileName);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download begining");
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download url:" + url);
            Log.d("ImageManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);
                    /* Open a connection to that URL. */
            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

                    /*
                     * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                     */
            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                    /*
                     * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
                     */
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

                    /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download ready in"
                    + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                    + " sec");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A NetworkOnMainThreadException means you are trying to access the network on the main thread, try creating a new Thread and accessing the network there.

> The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: ok thanks! but I dont really understand threads, could you edit the code or something? I never get them to work

Comment: try this link http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/05/painless-threading.html, there is examples in there of how to do threads in android. Something like `new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() { ... } }).start();` then include you code above inside the `run()` method